# Should I tell the boss anyway?

Tags: work-environment

A senior co-worker told me not to tell the boss he was doing things in a way they are not supposed to be done. He said that all the others before him did it his way and it's faster. Should I tell the boss anyway? Even if I think he will get in trouble?

The issue is about delivering the mail. The senior employee (regular carrier) takes short cuts (off route) and delivers mail from the left side of the vehicle .in areas where it is convenient, saving him a lot of time. This is what he told me not to tell the boss about.
  Delivering the mail from the left side means you are on the wrong side of the road. It can be dangerous.
  Taking short cuts ensures the route will be completed in the allotted time. He keeps his full time position as long as they don't have to split the route into two routes. However, if something happens off the route, as a mail carrier you are "screwed"
  He sits in the center of his vehicle. I use a right hand drive vehicle so I can't deliver from the left side. If I don't take the short cuts, I can't do the route in the allotted time.
   If they don't split the route, I don't get enough hours to keep the job. You have to be available at a moment's notice to cover for the regular carrier if need be. So you can't get another part time job.
  Also if I don't tell the postmaster, I feel like I'm lying through omission. I feel like I'm compromising my integrity. It's a small post office and it affects our relationship.
  I realize the regular carrier doesn't want to lose his retirement. He needs the full time hours.
  I'm sure he thinks it's okay since everybody else before him did it this way. 
  I don't want him to lose his retirement. 
  I love the job, but I can't afford to keep it.

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by telling the boss? In other words, what is the desired outcome?

Comment: Why are they not supposed to do it the faster way? Is the faster way dangerous? Does it have any negative impacts at all? If it doesn't, I would present it to your boss as a better alternative.

Comment: This is a bit too broad as stated. Are there legal issues? Compliance? Safety? Arbitrary policies? Quality? Costs?

Comment: Is the environment toxic? Why did the individual not go to the boss or bring the issue up in a meeting? What's the team relationship? How long has the boss been there VS the co-worker? Who has more field/industry knowledge? Who do you trust more? Please provide some more details.

Comment: This is way too broad. Please consult motivational posters until you explain your situation.

Comment: Depends if it is a safety violation. If duct taping sensors so can keep safety doors open on machines and that kind of thing. If its something trivial they are doing in Excel, does it really matter? Maybe voice your concerns. There is a reason things are to be done a certain way, give them enough rope to hang themselves. Maybe even smirk when they fired

Answer (score 3):

1. what are you hoping to accomplish by reporting this to the boss ? He gets demoted/fired so you have a better position to move to ? Then the answer is NO
2. is his shortcut affecting your work in any negative way ? When I say negative way, I don't mean that he is working faster and in turn I am expected to do more work. I am saying his using the shortcut causing you to work extra to fix problems ? If this is the case, by all means YES. But support your theory, don;t just say I think this is BAD
3. is his work ways causing degradation in the product your company puts out ? By all means YES. Nipping a downhill slope at the bud is the  best way to deal with.
4. what do you see being wrong with his approach if the jobs he is supposed to do, get done in a shorter time ? Again causing others to work more to catch up to him is not a good reason. If he is done faster than everyone else and have free time in his hands afterwards, you can kindly ask this person to help others with their tasks. After all he is getting paid to work 8 hour days. It is only fair if he is productive for those 8 hours.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what the shortcut is. How it is implemented and what it impacts on. Also just because your told it's not the right way to do something doesn't mean a lot.

I use many shortcuts I have worked out over the years which make me a lot more efficient. But I also know the pitfalls associated with each and how to make sure they are not impacting on the end product, which is why I do not teach them to trainees.

If it's something that impacts on physical safety or was illegal then I would tell the boss.

If it's a procedure that increases efficiency then I would be more reluctant to do so. But if the boss asked me, I would tell the truth.

Complaining about a senior or superior to the boss rarely works out well even if there is a legitimate and pressing reason to do so. So pick this battle wisely.